# Error: (node:13452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.roles.cache.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const ms = require("ms");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "mute", 
  description: "Mute la persone mentionné",
  async execute (client, message, args) {

    let member = message.member;
  let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
  let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');
  let muteTime = (args[1] || '24d');
  if (!member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return
```

i dont understand this bug, can you help me please ?

Comment: use `.get()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: Happy to help, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get()` instead of `.find()`

Old Code:

```
let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');
```

New Code:

```
let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('<id>');
```